# how to import file based on date on excel

Tags: vba, excel

Please assist as i am new to vba and excel macro. Thank you very much.
I need to get the coding for the file and make it run on a daily basis so the process is easier.

Photo of the code requirement i need
[image]

This is what i have done so far but the code does not works

```
Option Explicit

Sub test2()
    'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim date5 As String


    date5 = Sheets("Main").Range("C3")
    Path = "D:\Users\451269\Desktop\MUREX compare\\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.csv")
    '--------------------------------------------
    'OPEN EXCEL FILES
    Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    wbk.Close True
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheet("FXSM").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Filename = Dir

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I'm sorry, but this is not a site where people write code for free. We can help you in solving your problems, but first you have to try to do something by yourself. You can easily find some parts of code you need on this site, like "how to open file with VBA". And there's macro recorder in Excel. Use them and come back with things that don't work.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Flagged this one as too broad. Please read ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), start writing code and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is move the line of code `wbk.Close True` after `ActiveSheet.Paste`.